# How to properly remove localhost DNS settings on Mac so real world DNS resolution can happen

Tags: linux, vagrant

I’m having an issue removing some local DNS settings on my Mac that’s running Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite).

I normally use the `/etc/hosts` file to direct requests from development sites to my guest Vagrant VM. Sometimes I use the live site’s URL in development to eliminate having to replace paths when I migrate my DB.

In this instance I had the following record:

```
192.168.50.4 example.com www.example.com
```

The above IP is my Vagrant VM’s IP.

I’ve migrated the site to production and I cannot get Chrome to connect to the live site on my server. When I use `ping` and `traceroute` that hostname, the Mac still resolves to the `192.168.50.4` Vagrant VM address that I have already removed.

When I visit the website on my mobile phone I’m getting the expected behavior.

So far I’ve done the following:

1. Removed the record from my `/etc/hosts` file.
2. Rebooted my Macintosh.
3. Cleaned the local cache [as described here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516).
4. Flushed Chrome’s DNS cache by visiting here: `chrome://net-internals/#dns`.
5. Rebooted my Macintosh again.
6. Reloaded and re-provisioned my Vagrant VM.
7. Rebooted.

I can’t seem to make my Macintosh connect to live site on the web. I’ve used this process for the last 10-15 projects I’ve developed.

Any ideas on how I might prevent my machine from looking up the domain on my Vagrant VM?

Update: running `dscacheutil -q host`reveals the following entries:

```
name: example.net
alias: # VAGRANT: 53475745d1ed12f00441552188bfdd8b (default) / 0eb4854a-a516-4d34-ac43-397240944175
ip_address: 192.168.50.4

name: www.example.net
alias: # VAGRANT: 53475745d1ed12f00441552188bfdd8b (default) / 0eb4854a-a516-4d34-ac43-397240944175
ip_address: 192.168.50.4
```

Still not sure why I can't clear this using any of the commands recommended by Apple.

Comment: I can access the site just fine from my droid. Circumstantial, yes, but good enough for me to declare that this is in fact a DNS issue. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: I tried all of the commands for good measure, testing each one, multiple times...quite puzzling. Just logged into backend of this WordPress site from my droid. Still can't resolve DNS from Mac.

Comment: Just did, resolves to my guest VM, even though I've done all of the above steps.

Comment: Resolved. Issue was with my vagrant host updater plugin which kept persisting host records into my `/etc/hosts` file even after I removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone running into this problem, there is a simple solution:

1. Check your `/etc/hosts` file.
2. Remove the necessary entry.
3. Double check that the hosts file entries have been removed: `dscacheutil -q host`
4. Clear your local cache, depending on your OS version ([reference here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516)).
5. Check your Vagrantfile and make sure you're not using a plugin to update the hosts file during provisioning.
6. Reload vagrant and provision `vagrant reload --provision`
7. Check your hosts file again, go allll the way to the bottom.

I happen to be using a Vagrant plugin that caused the host file to be updated during provisioning, but hey I set this up months ago and forgot.

Godspeed.